# jquery remove() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list

```
<ul id="serial_list" class="list-group scroll">
    <li class="list-group-item template">template</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">eee</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to delete each item based on each element of an array.

Approach1:

```
numbers = ["SNID", "abc", "eee", "SNID", "abc"];
// find each li
var list = $(serial_list).find('li:not(.template)');

numbers.forEach(function(number) {
    $(list).each(function(index, item) {
        // console.log(number);
        if (number == $(item).html()) {
            $(item).remove();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The expected result will be

```
<ul id="serial_list" class="list-group scroll">
    <li class="list-group-item template">template</li>
</ul>
```

However, the actual result is

```
<ul id="serial_list" class="list-group scroll">
    <li class="list-group-item template">template</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
</ul>
```

The number of times calling remove() is the same as the length of the array.

However, if I update the list when loop each number (Approach2) , the result is what I expect.

Approach2:

```
numbers = ["SNID", "abc", "eee", "SNID", "abc"];
var list;

numbers.forEach(function(number) {
    list = $(serial_list).find('li:not(.template)');
    $(list).each(function(index, item) {
        // console.log(number);
        if (number == $(item).html()) {
            $(item).remove();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The result is expected, but this kills the performance.

Why the approach1 does not work?

I am curious about removing `return false`, since approach1 will work if the list have no duplicate item.

```
<ul id="serial_list" class="list-group scroll">
    <li class="list-group-item template">template</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">eee</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">fff</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">ggg</li>
</ul>
```

Approach1:

```
numbers = ["SNID", "abc", "eee", "fff", "ggg"];
// find each li
var list = $(serial_list).find('li:not(.template)');

numbers.forEach(function(number) {
    $(list).each(function(index, item) {
        // console.log(number);
        if (number == $(item).html()) {
            $(item).remove();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

In this case, approach1 will work as I expect. Why the `return false` do not mess up in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: You need an each, within the each, so it finds multiples  - approach1 finds one and then carries on

Comment: Since you are using `$(item).remove();` you need to update the reference again in  next iteration thus Approach 1 doesn't work

Comment: If you're looking for optimised solution use `indexOf`. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zurkd3hq/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return false` breaks the each loop iteration.

Ref:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Remove it and will work fine.

Code:

```
numbers.forEach(function (number) {
    $(list).each(function (index, item) {
        if (number == $(item).html()) {
            $(item).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zurkd3hq/

Comment: Please see my edit. If the list has no duplicate items, approach 1 will work as I expect. Why `return false` do not screw up in such case?

Comment: Because aside the return falsem there is only one occurence per key, so it doesn't matter if you break the loop

Comment: `list` is already jQuery object, no need of wrapping it again

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `$(item).remove();` you need to update the reference again in  next iteration thus Approach 1 doesn't work

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) along with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var list = $(serial_list).find('li:not(.template)');    
list.filter(function(){
    return numbers.indexOf($(item).html()) > -1;
    //return $.inArray(numbers, $(item).html());
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't just this has to be done:

```
$('#serial_list').find('li:not(.template)').remove();
```

instead of looping in the array.

Comment: I do not want to remove all the items in the list. I only want to remove the element which is also in the array.

Comment: @user3378223 ohh i see.

Answer (score 0):

remove `return false;` from Approach 1 and it will output as you want.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="serial_list" class="list-group scroll">
    <li class="list-group-item template">template</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">eee</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var numbers = ["SNID", "abc", "eee", "SNID", "abc"];
// find each li
var list = $('#serial_list').find('li:not(.template)');

list.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (numbers.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/52Lckqob/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = ["SNID", "abc", "eee", "SNID", "abc"];
var $list = $('#serial_list').find('li:not(.template)');

$list.filter(function(){
  return (numbers.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1);
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="serial_list" class="list-group scroll">
    <li class="list-group-item template">template</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">eee</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">SNID</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">abc</li>
</ul>
```